# Trivial Projection of Forcing Posets and Generics

Tags: set-theory, forcing

$\pi : Q \rightarrow P$ is a projection of two forcing poset if and only if

(1) $\pi$ is order preserving, onto, and maps $0_Q$ to $0_P$.

(2) For all $q \in Q$ and $p' \in P$, if $p' \geq \pi(q)$, then there exists a $q' \geq q$ such that $\pi(q') = p'$.

$\pi$ is a trivial projection if and only if $\pi(q_1) = \pi(q_2)$ implies $q_1 \not \perp q_2$.

In $\textit{Proper Forcing}$ by Uri Abraham, he claims if $G$ is $P$-generic, then $\pi^{-1}(G)$ is $Q$-generic, when $\pi$ is a trivial projection.

I can't seem to show that $\pi^{-1}(G)$ is a filter in $Q$. In particular, I can not show that two elements of $\pi^{-1}(G)$ has a compatible extension in $\pi^{-1}(G)$.

Abraham forcing notation is the opposite of Jech and Kunen; however, I will use his convention here.

One possible approach: let $q_1, q_2 \in \pi^{-1}(G)$. $\pi(q_1)$ and $\pi_1(q_2)$ are in $G$. Hence, there exists an extension $r \in G$ such that $r \geq \pi(q_1)$ and $r \geq \pi(q_2)$. By (2), there exists $q_1' \geq q_1$ and $q_2' \geq q_1$ such that $\pi(q_1') = r = \pi(q_2')$. By the definition of trivial, $q_1' \not \perp q_2'$. However, I do not see how to show that there exists a compatible extension in $\pi^{-1}(G)$.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Also this is not a standalone text (although it can be read as such), but rather a chapter in the Handbook of Set Theory.

Comment: I also take that $\not\perp$ means "compatible"?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes. I think Kunen uses this notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you don't mind, but I will change your forcing order direction (i.e. I will extend downward).

Your approach works; it just needs a small step at the end. Let me just reiterate to fix my notation:

Let $q_1,q_2\in\pi^{-1}[G]$. Since $G$ is a filter, there is a $p\in G$ such that $p\leq q_1,q_2$. By (2) there are $q_1'\leq q_1$ and $q_2'\leq q_2$ such that $\pi(q_1')=\pi(q_2')=p$.

I now claim that the image of the set of common extensions of $q_1'$ and $q_2'$ is dense below $p$. Indeed, take $p^*\leq p$. By (2) there are $q_1^*\leq q_1'$ and $q_2^*\leq q_2'$ such that $\pi(q_1^*)=\pi(q_2^*)=p^*$ and these two are compatible, by triviality, with common extension $q^*$. But then, by monotonicity, we have $\pi(q^*)\leq p^*$.

By genericity there is a $q_0\leq q_1,q_2$ such that $\pi(q_0)\in G$, as required.

Comment: In Jerusalem, and in fact in some other places too, it's quite standard to force "up" rather than "down".

Comment: @AsafKaragila I know. I was being deliberately chauvinistic and West-centric, just to spite you ;).

Comment: Me? I force downwards.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Your general geographic location then.

Comment: Well, it's about half-half here, actually.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Do they still use the term generic "filter"?

Comment: @William: Huh???

Comment: @AsafKaragila Usually filter means closed above and has some compatible element below. When you switch direction of the ordering, the definition of a "generic" switch in this regard too. So would do people who use the upward forcing notation still use the term "generic filter". Does anyone call this an ideal. I think Abraham still uses the term filter, though.

Comment: @William: You are thinking about it wrong. Filter is not about up or down. It is closed under "weaker" conditions. And last time we spoke, Uri still used the term generic filter.

Answer (score 2):

What's involved here is a special case of the following more general phenomenon. Suppose (as in the usual forcing set-up) $P$ is a poset in some transitive model $M$ and $G$ (usually not in $M$) is a subset of $P$ such that (1) $G$ is closed upward [I'm using the non-Jerusalem forcing convention: stronger = lower.] (2) every two members of $G$ are compatible and (3) $G$ meets every dense subset of $P$ that is in $M$. [These hypotheses almost say that $G$ is $M$-generic; the difference is that, in (2), any two elements of $G$ are required merely to have a lower bound in $P$, not necessarily in $G$.] Then $G$ is $M$-generic.

Proof: The only part of genericity that I haven't assumed is that, if $p_1,p_2\in G$, then they have a lower bound not merely in $P$ but in $G$. To prove this, consider the set
$$
D=\{q\in P: \text{ Either }q\leq p_1\text{ and }q\leq p_2\text{ or }q\text{ is incompatible with at least one of }p_1,p_2\}.
$$
$D$ is a subset of $P$ and an element of $M$. I'll show that it is dense in $P$. Once this is shown, I'll know that $G$ contains some $q\in D$. Being in $G$, this $q$ must be compatible with $p_1$ and with $p_2$, by my assumption (2). So the only way it can be in $D$ is to be an extension of both of them, which is what I needed.

So it remains only to prove that $D$ is dense, but this is easy. Let an arbitrary $r\in P$ be given; I want an extension $q$ in $D$. If $r$ is incompatible with $p_1$, then $r$ itself is in $D$, so I'm done, with $q=r$. Otherwise, let $r'$ be a common extension of $r$ and $p_1$. If $r'$ is incompatible with $p_2$, then $r'\in D$ so I'm done, with $q=r'$. Otherwise, let $q$ be a common extension of $r'$ and $p_2$, and again this $q$ does what I needed.